# "news fal migration" settings

Tags: typo3-7.6.x, tx-news

I use the typo3 plugin "news_fal_migration" by Georg Ringer.

https://github.com/ext-news/news_fal_migration

When I run the script ...

```
./typo3cms newsfalmigration:run --start=true
```

I receive the following message

> There are *863* media records which are using the old media relation. This wizard will copy the files to "fileadmin/_migrated/news_uploads".
> **Important:** The **first** local storage inside "fileadmin/" will be used for the migration. If you have multiple storages, only enable the one which should be used for the migration.

How can I activate this?

Upgrade:
news 3.2.8 -> 6.3.0 and typo3 6.2 -> 7.6

Comment: what is your problem? do you want another path for the converted files? do you get, aside from that notice, an error message? ...

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not know how I can activate in typo3 "fileadmin" so that this error message does not come. Yes, I get an error message that there are no access rights. That is, if I empty the "typo3temp", the files are created without authorization. Example: Instead of "-755" these files are marked with "----".

Comment: if you have files with access rights `---` nobody could access them. not very useful. except you have an non unix like operating system, which has other access mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

go to the install tool: there you can configure the filemask which TYPO3 should use if it creates new files and folders.

by default the filemasks are set to `644` or `755`. As for most webspaces the apache user is another one than the ssh or ftp user you get problems if you upload, create or edit files via ssh/ftp and then want to use these files in TYPO3. So I normaly change the filemask to 664 and 775 as my ssh/ftp user shares the group with the apache user.

If there is no common group you need to loose all restrictions and set 666 and 777 as filemask. you also need to do this for your ssh/ftp user (-> `umask`) or each file/folder individually (->`chmod`).
Otherwise you and TYPO3 can not access files and folders created by the other.